# Mix of template and struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have a template class defined as follow :

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass { };
```

In this class, I need a struct that contains one member of type T1. How can I do that ?

I tried the following, but it didn't work :

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass {
    typedef struct {
        T1 templateMember;
        // rest of members
    } myStruct;

    // rest of class definition
};
```

EDIT: As requested, I use VS2008 and get the following error :

```
'MyClass<T1,T2>::myStruct' uses undefined class 'T1'
```

Comment: The code you posted compiles in VS 2005. I also managed to instantiate MyClass with int as T1 and T2.

Comment: Yep, please specify compiler/platform and the error message, rather than just "it didn't work."

Comment: By any chance do you write "class T1 templateMember;" instead of just "T1 templateMember;" ?

Comment: Looking at the reported error, I'm guessing that the problem is not in the code you have posted.  What line *exactly* has the error?

Comment: The error is in the struct definition, on the line `T1 templateMember;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove typedef:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass {
    struct myStruct{
        T1 templateMember;
        // rest of members
    } ;
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain why he should remove the typedef? Both look like valid C++ code.

Comment: It kind of curios example in question well compiled in g++. But MSVC (it kind of assumption) uses another engine to late names resolve. 
typedef struct... declares anonymous that cannot be referenced and compiler cannot assume entity it deals. Also compilable example (but not in g++) typedef typename struct { - in this case MSVC exactly knows that deals with struct.

Once again - it my assumption

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T1>
struct myStruct{
    T1 templateMember;
    // rest of members
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass {

    myStruct<T1> mystruct;

    // rest of class definition
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is *exactly* what you typed?

```
    template <class T1, class T2>
    class MyClass {
    public:
        typedef struct {
            T1 templateMember;
            // rest of members
        } myStruct;

        // rest of class definition
    };

    MyClass<int, float> c;
    MyClass<int, float>::myStruct ms;
```

This compiles and works just fine for me in VS2008 SP1.  Note that I added the *public:* so that I could access *myStruct*, but it does not affect the correctness of the rest of the declaration.

Comment: It's a simplified version of my code. But to make sure, I tried in a separate file, and it works indeed. But not in the "complicated" version. I guess the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Which is why we need the non-compiling version.